# trying to add nested comments with closure_tree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

I'm trying to add nested comments using the closure_tree gem – and this sitepoint guide http://www.sitepoint.com/nested-comments-rails/

I, unfortunately, keep coming up with this error after replying to a comment:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in CommentsController#create
SQLite3::SQLException: near "DESC1": syntax error: SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."parent_id" = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC1

and its pointing to line 18 which is in my 'create' method – which is the `if @comment.save` line call me crazy but i don't see the syntax error

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Here is my Comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @comments = Comment.hash_tree
  end

  def new
    @comment = Comment.new(parent_id: params[:parent_id])
  end

  def create
    if params[:comment][:parent_id].to_i > 0
      parent = Comment.find_by_id(params[:comment].delete(:parent_id))
      @comment = parent.children.build(comment_params)
    else
      @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    end

    if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = 'Your comment was successfully added!'
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
  def comment_params
     params.require(:comment).permit(:title, :body, :author)
  end
end
```

Here is my comments model, mostly empty

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_tree order: 'created_at DESC1'
end
```

Comment: please post your comment model

Comment: Just posted it up there. It's mostly empty. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your Comment model.  Change  'DESC1' to 'DESC'

Comment: that's embarrassing... Thank you.